# LibGDX - Creating a sheared texture on a cetain position

Tags: java, android, libgdx, render

So I'm working on a simple card game with LibGDX and AndroidStudio in java.
I'm currently trying to figure out how to draw a deck of cards looking 3-dimensional.
To archieve that I took a simple card texture and drew it 20 times on top of itself. I originally used

```
myBatch.draw(cardBack, width, height, transformMatrix);
```

method to add a little shaering. Unfortunatately this method doesn't let you choose the position you want to draw your texture on.

So I instead created a Sprite with my textureRegion, set the position and size and archieved the shearing effect by setting the transformationMatrix of my SpriteBatch.

```
public void render(float delta) {
    setBlack();  //clears the screen
    myBatch.setTransformMatrix(renderMatrix);
    myBatch.begin();
    cardBack.setPosition(Game.realWidth / 2f - cardBack.getWidth() / 2f,
            Game.realHeight/2f - cardBack.getHeight() / 2);

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        cardBack.setY(cardBack.getY() + 5);
        cardBack.draw(myBatch);      
    }
    myBatch.end();
    myStage.act();
    myStage.draw();
}
```

The matrix simply has a little shearing transformation:

```
public TestScreen(){
    ...
    renderMatrix = new Matrix4().set(new Affine2.shear(0.5f, 0));
}
```

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDa2T.jpg)

Not quite what I wanted as the cards should stack vertically on top of eachother. I simply don't understand why their x coordinate changes.

To solve this I shifted the cards a little bit when drawing them:

```
public void render(float delat){
    ...
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        cardBack.setPosition(cardBack.getX() - 1, cardBack.getY() + 5);
        cardBack.draw(myBatch);
}
```

[The result was quite what I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlcyr.jpg), but still I don't like hardcoding this "-1" as it doesn't seem right.

**Are there any other solutions for this problem? Is there maybe another draw function that I could use that lets me specify the position of my image?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're shearing with the projection matrix, so it's shearing the entire screen. The Y axis is distorted to an angle, creating the appearance of the cards being at different x positions.

Comment: You could shear individual cards using an Affine2 instead of a weird projection matrix. I think SpriteBatch has a draw method that takes an Affine2 as a parameter. But wouldn't it be simpler and look more realistic to use a PerspectiveCamera and design your game in 3D? You can use DecalBatch or the FlexBatch third party library to do flat sprites in 3D space.

Comment: My problem with the method was that it didn't let me specify the position of my card. I googled  quite a while but I found out you could simply use 



affine2.setTranslation(card_back.getX(), card_back.getY());    

But thanks anyways!